# Map inside a map - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have tried putting a map inside a map. The innermost map is running multiple times because of the map surrounding it. The requirement is to get the links mapped to the description (I've used # for some links).

Below is the data:

```
    {
        title: 'test',
        description: ['Team', 'History', 'Contact us', 'Locations'],
        linkto: ['#','#','#','#'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Categories',
        description: ['test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'],
        linkto: ['#','#','#','#'],
    },
    {
        title: 'Legal',
        description: ['Privacy policy', 'Terms of use'],
        linkto: ['#','#',],
    },
    {
        title: 'Social',
        description: ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Instagram', 'Youtube', 'LinkedIn'],
        linkto: ['https://www.facebook.com', 'https://twitter.com/', 'https://www.instagram.com/', 'https://www.youtube.com/', 'https://www.linkedin.com']
    },
];

**Below is the mapping code:********************************************

<Grid container spacing={4} justify="space-evenly">
                    {footers.map((footer) => (
                        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} key={footer.title}>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
                                {footer.title}
                            </Typography>
                            <ul>
                                {footer.description.map((item, index) => (
                                        footer.linkto.map((link, subindex) => (
                                            <Link key={subindex} href={link} variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
                                                <li key={index}>{item}</li>
                                            </Link>
                                        ))
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Beyond the fact that you are creating invalid children of `<ul>` what is the specific problem or error? You only told us what you are trying to do but not what's wrong or what the expected results are

Comment: the map inside the map is printing everything 5 times. for eg: in Social, Facebook is getting printed 5 times with all five links, and so is Twitter and so on. The expected results are that Facebook should have its own link only and the same goes true for others.

Comment: Pick just one of them to map (linkTo or description) and use the index to get value from the other array within that map. Assumes they all having appropriate lengths

Comment: @BhuwanAdhikari That really doesn't make sense since associated values of each are needed in same component

Comment: @BhuwanAdhikari didn't work, still gonna replicate 5 times

Comment: @charlietfl tried, can you explain more. I'm still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they each have same lengths for each item just map one of the arrays and use the index to get the value from the one you are not mapping.

Also for valid markup the `<li>` needs to be outside as child of the `<ul>` not nested as child of `<Link>` and you don't need a `key` on the inner element

Something like:

```
{footer.description.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <Link href={footer.linkTo[index]} variant="subtitle1" color="textSecondary">
         {item}
       </Link>  
     </li>                                   
)}}
```